# How to send multiple fields to vue-x store?

Tags: vue.js

I am building multiple rating fields using v-for like this:

```html
<div class="ratings">
    <div class="rating" v-for="rating in applicationViewCv.jobPostRatingFields" :key="rating.id">
      <label :for="rating.id">
        <b>{{rating.field}}</b>
      </label>
      <v-rating
        @input="addRating($event, rating.id)"
        :value="rating.id"
        background-color="indigo lighten-3"
        color="indigo"
        :dense="true"
        :hover="true"
        size="15"
        :id="rating.id"
      ></v-rating>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my script I want to build an object and pass it to vue-x actions to be sent to the server, I don't know how should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let store =new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
   ratings: [
    {
     id: 1,
      value: 4
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      value: 3
    }
    ],
  },
  actions: {
    SET_RATING({ state, commit}, {rating, value}) {
     let ratings = state.ratings.map(el => {
        if (rating.id == el.id) {
           el.value = value
         }
         return el;
      })
     commit('RATING', ratings)
    },
    // or make some async operation
    async SET_RATING_OTHER({ state, commit}, {rating, value}) {
      try {
        let response = await this.$axios.post(`/api/ratings`, { rating, value });         
         commit('RATING', response)
      } catch (error) {
        //catch error
     }
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    RATING(state, ratings) {
     state.ratings = ratings
    }
  },
  getters: {
   ratings: state => {
      return state.ratings;
    },
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  computed: {
    ratings() {
     return this.$store.getters.ratings
    }
  },
 watch: {
   ratings(newVal) {
    //only to check
    console.log(newVal)
   }
 },
 methods: {
  setRating(rating, value) {
   // alert('set rating id: ' + rating.id + ' to ' + value)
     this.$store.dispatch('SET_RATING', {rating, value})
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.9/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.1/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
     <div v-for="rating in ratings" :key="rating.id">
              <v-rating
                @input="setRating(rating, $event)"
              
                :value="rating.value"
                color="yellow darken-3"
                background-color="grey darken-1"
                empty-icon="$ratingFull"
                hover
                ></v-rating>
          </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but my main problem is that ratings are not predefined. each time server sends different number of ratings with different ids and i dont know how to build ratings array of objects and set the values for each object